# Value Change Handler with multiple variables

Tags: java, gwt

I have a widget that extends composite and implements HasValueChangeHandlers that contains 3 Date objects: beg, current, and end.  I am trying to be able to add a value change handler that will be able to tell which date object changed; but it's not immediately apparent to me the best way to do that.

What is the best way to solve this?  How do I know which Date object has changed without going back and comparing the values?

Should I create empty classes for each variable and pass them as the source then switch on comparing the source class of the event in the onValueChange method?  It seems like there should be a better way...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best approach is to take advantage that the date objects themselves implement `HasValueChangedHandlers`. In your composite class, you can add a changed handler to each of them so that you know which one changed.  In fact, if it is the same behavior that you want to apply to all of them you might as well you set the same handler for all. For example:

```
 public MyClass extends Composite implements HasValueChangedHandler{
       private DateBox beg;
       private DateBox current;
       private DateBox end;   

       //.... rest of the code..

       public HandlerRegistration addValueChangedHanlder(ValueChangedHandler<Date> h){
                 beg.addValueChangedHandler(h);
                 current.addValueChangedHandler(h);
                 end.addValueChangedHandler(h);

       }
        //.... rest of the code..

 }
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm using the right Date object for that.  I was using java.util.Date  it doesn't seem that I can add a value change handler directly to that object unless I'm missing something...  Do you mean I should extend the Date class to implement HasValueChangeHandler?  I'm a little new at this so I may be missing something that should be obvious.  Also maybe I should clarify that the behavior will be different depending on the variable that was changed.

Comment: java.util.Date is not a `GWT` object so it wouldn't make sense to add a Changed handler to them because they are just representations. java.util.Date will not render into any graphical content, hence it won't change from the user interface perspective.

Comment: However, the value changed handler for `DateBox` gives you a java.util.Date Object containing the new Date selected.

Comment: Maybe I should explain myself a little better.  I'm creating a timeline widget; the timeline has a HTML5 canvas that works as a display and reacts to events (clicks) to change the dates.  There are also DateBoxes to be able to numerically change the dates displayed by the timeline.  I have the internal events of the widget working so an event on one correctly updates the other.  What I need now is to be able to react to these change events externally.  So I figured use a value change handler which is fired when the dates are changed. It sounds like I'll have to create specific events for each.